# CakePHP 3: Exception not Found

Tags: php, cakephp, exception

I've written several placeholder functions in my User model. All I want them to do is throw the `NotImplementedException()` [provided by CakePHP](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/errors.html#other-built-in-exceptions). The function is nice and simple and I have tried it several different ways.

```
public function canConvert() {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Error:Class 'App\Model\Entity\NotImplementedException' not found

```
public function canConvert() {
    throw new \NotImplementedException();
}
```

Error:Class 'NotImplementedException' not found

The only way I could find to do this was this way.

```
public function canConvert() {
    throw new \Cake\Network\Exception\NotImplementedException();
}
```

I tried to do a `use Cake\Network\Exception;` and the top and just throw a `NotImplementedException()` but that didn't work.

Comment: Thanks @MagnusEriksson that worked!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you just do

```
use Cake\Network\Exception;
```

you've only imported the namespace, not the classes under it. To reference a class under that namespace, you would then need to do:

```
throw new Exception\NotImplementedException();
```

PHP doesn't automatically import all classes under a namespace.

Read more in the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php